# matlab matrix get values in different columns

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let my matrix be:

```
        A = 
        [1,2,3;
        4,5,6;
        7,8,9];
```

I have to extract the values in (1,2), (2,3), (3,1).
I tried the following:

```
        c = [2,3,1]';

        A(:, c)
```

but it gives a 3x3 matrix instead of 3x1.

How can I do it efficiently in matlab?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate case, if only the SO search system was better!

Comment: @Divakar Mark it as duplicate if you find it. It really looks like that this has been answered before in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to extract arbitrary values from a matrix is to use linear indices.

You can use [sub2ind](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

```
ind=sub2ind(size(A),[1 2 3], [2 3 1]);
val=A(ind);
```